# Java with many Forms

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

If I am going about this all wrong please let me know.

What I have:

- JFrame
- JDialog
- Main executable

What I want to do

Have a way to open the `JDialog` (the class extends the `JDialog`) and have the `JFrame` pause and wait for the `JDialog` to be closed before doing anything else. The `JDialog` is actually just hidden so I can then call a method to pull the data that the user input.

My Issues

- Cant figure out how to make the JFrame wait until the JDialog is closed before executing more code
- If possible I would like the JFrame to be disabled until the JDialog is closed.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is nothing more than using a ***modal*** JDialog. When you construct the dialog, when you call its constructor, be sure to set its modality type to ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL.

e.g.,

```
JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(myJFrame, "Dialog", 
       Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

Please read: [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Comment: myJFrame, is that the JFrame or the JDialog from my example?

Comment: @Brandon: `"JDialog from my example..."` -- um,... you don't post any example code that I can see. Perhaps you can guess whether myJFrame represents a JFrame or a JDialog. I have confidence that you can figure this out.

Comment: @Brandon: sorry for the sarcasm, but seriously, myJFrame is going to represent the calling JFrame, the window that is the parent of the dialog. I thought that it should be obvious by my calling it "myJFrame" which is why I gave it that name. If you need more specific help, then by all means, post example code, preferably a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read the link).